# printStackTrace() в Android приложении

Tags: java, android, исключения

ведет ли вызов метода trowable.printStackTrace() к крашу и остановке приложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не приведет. Вызов метода `.printStackTrace()` просто выведет список вызовов методов до данной ошибки. То есть:

1. Вызов метода1 в классе2.
2. Вызова метода 2 из метода 1.
3. Ошибка в методе 2 на строке 13.

Метод вызывается НА ошибке и дает информации о ее происхождении.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
   //логика
} catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace() 
}
```

Это не приведет к падению

Comment: Это просто скроет ошибку!

Comment: Ошибку не скроет, а перехватить. Но вопрос не в этом был то

Answer (score 1):

Если `throwable != null` то все нормально, краша не будет.

Смотря где и как использовать.